PermissionError [WinError 5] using winreg.QueryValueEx() in Python
Here is where I open the key (no errors):
key = reg.OpenKey(reg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
                  r"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment",
                  0,
                  reg.KEY_SET_VALUE  
                  )

And the query where the error is thrown:
current_path = reg.QueryValueEx(key, "Path")[0]

 File "C:\src\jbpm\file.py", line 31, in add_dir_to_path
    current_path = reg.QueryValueEx(key, "Path")[0]
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied

This is being run in PowerShell run in administrator mode, which I thought would be enough.
Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

you need KEY_QUERY_VALUE but not KEY_SET_VALUE for QueryValueEx

Oops, I figured it out. If you want to query and set, you need both permissions:
reg.KEY_QUERY_VALUE | reg.KEY_SET_VALUE

Thanks to @RbMm for the advice
